# How to find climbing on stairs using android?

Tags: android, android-sensors

I am doing android application related to pedometer using accelerometer and GPS. 
I can find user is walking or not based on this formula

```
speed = Math.abs(x+y+z - last_x - last_y - last_z)/ diffTime * 10000;
```

I can not find when the user is climbing in stairs in indoor.

I can find using GPS, it is possible to find altitude. So I can conclude whether the user is climbing or not based on this following function.

```
double altitude=location.getAltitude();
```

But GPS is not give good Altitude accuracy in indoor. Is it possible to find climbing on stairs in indoor using accelerometer?

Thanks for your answer.

Comment: please restructure question and show some initial attempts made, we will not simply do your work for you.

Comment: @Graham Smith: Can you get me now?

Comment: Hi, just saw this question, I need to do the same thing. Have you found the correct formula for stairs counting yet?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

He. The acceleratometer sound like a good idea.

Create simple app to store data from accelerometer and plot it on the display. Record many sample data passes on stairs (up/down). Then create approximation function which describe that kind of movement. Then in your application track accelerometer change and check how close it is to the given function. Of course you should take in to the account some error margin.